# rails3 displays all records at the end of the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a index action in my rails 3.2.6(ruby 1.9.3) app. In the view i am simply looping over all the records in the database.When I hit the index action in the browser it displays all the records present in the database as an array at the end of the page any pointers what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing the code for your view would help a lot. My guess, you are likely printing out the value of the `each` call. `each` returns the array after it loops through all of the elements. If you are using erb, below should work:

Change

`<%= @records.each do |record| %>`

to

`<% @records.each do |record| %>`

Comment: Thanks @cjhveal sounds dumb but i actually made this mistake.Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. Easy mistake to make :)